# What is the intuitive explanation for what a tensor is?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I'm not major in math or physics, but I've seen **tensor** many times in the papers regarding to robotics and deep learning.

Can someone give me a novice-level intuitive explanation for what a tensor is? With illustrative figures would be awesome!

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444412/qualitatively-what-is-the-difference-between-a-matrix-and-a-tensor?rq=1) question? That question also links to another one.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors